# Visual Studio Online - Error TF215070 with XAML Build Definition

Tags: tfs, build, azure-devops

I am using Visual Studio Online and recently I created a XAML Build Definition for testing purposes.

Now I would like to delete it, but it is not possible. I always get the following error message:

> 500: TF215070: The build URI vstfs:///Build/Build/135 is not valid.
>   Make sure that this build exists and has not been
>   deleted.TFS.WebApi.Exception: TF215070: The build URI
>   vstfs:///Build/Build/135 is not valid. Make sure that this build
>   exists and has not been deleted.    at k
>   (https://xxx.visualstudio.com/_static/tfs/20150901T200043/_scripts/TFS/min/corejs?v=8oe2VxmtIRMt5sf9uSOR8Ipd_3B9HcCaQWsEjeX4ZOs1:40:279)
>   at Anonymous function
>   (https://xxx.visualstudio.com/_static/tfs/20150901T200043/_scripts/TFS/min/corejs?v=8oe2VxmtIRMt5sf9uSOR8Ipd_3B9HcCaQWsEjeX4ZOs1:40:2958)
>   at d
>   (https://xxx.visualstudio.com/_static/tfs/20150901T200043/_scripts/TFS/min/corejs?v=8oe2VxmtIRMt5sf9uSOR8Ipd_3B9HcCaQWsEjeX4ZOs1:40:635)
>   at Anonymous function
>   (https://xxx.visualstudio.com/_static/tfs/20150901T200043/_scripts/TFS/min/corejs?v=8oe2VxmtIRMt5sf9uSOR8Ipd_3B9HcCaQWsEjeX4ZOs1:40:2897)
>   at l
>   (https://xxx.visualstudio.com/_static/tfs/20150901T200043/_scripts/TFS/min/q.js:27:8115)
>   at Anonymous function
>   (https://xxx.visualstudio.com/_static/tfs/20150901T200043/_scripts/TFS/min/q.js:27:8338)
>   at when
>   (https://xxx.visualstudio.com/_static/tfs/20150901T200043/_scripts/TFS/min/q.js:27:3759)
>   at u.promiseDispatch
>   (https://xxx.visualstudio.com/_static/tfs/20150901T200043/_scripts/TFS/min/q.js:27:2812)
>   at Anonymous function
>   (https://xxx.visualstudio.com/_static/tfs/20150901T200043/_scripts/TFS/min/q.js:27:1631)
>   at t
>   (https://xxx.visualstudio.com/_static/tfs/20150901T200043/_scripts/TFS/min/q.js:27:5773)
>
> Session Id: 2e62bb04-dcfd-4e81-8281-23c9ecf6e22e

I previously removed all the builds that were completed and there is no queued build.

Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: As it's a XAML build definition can you delete it from inside Visual Studio?

Comment: How do you delete that build definition? Any steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Vicky: I went to the Build page in VSO and then right clicked on the build definition, then clicked on Delete...
@DaveShaw: even from Visual Studio I was not able to delete it.

Finally on Sunday eve I could delete it. I ran a build with this build definition, and then kept it (I used to delete them all before). Then I right click on the build definition and clicked on Delete... and it worked!

Answer (score 2):

For me, the TF215070 error was occuring because there was a build queued up. Since my checkout + build was so slow, check-ins would prevent me from deleting from the VSO panel. I went to queued builds, cancelled -- and then was able to delete.